# Why Memory usage increase even if there are not user on my Rails app on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

[image]

This is "Memory Usage" of my Rails app on Heroku.

It start with 290MB at 2AM and, at 12PM is at 412MB! My web app has something like 5-10users and I pretty sure that during night time nobody are using it.
So why memory Usage is increasing?
How Could I inspect some reasons?

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'puma'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'connection_pool'
```

**Production.rb**

```
 config.cache_store = :dalli_store,
                    (ENV["MEMCACHIER_SERVERS"] || "").split(","),
                    {:username => ENV["MEMCACHIER_USERNAME"],
                     :password => ENV["MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD"],
                     :failover => true,
                     :socket_timeout => 1.5,
                     :socket_failure_delay => 0.2,
                     :pool_size => 5
                    }
```

**MemCachier Analytics**

[image]

Comment: Maybe you've got some crazy over-the-top caching going on somewhere(?)

Comment: I'm using dalli_store + Memcahier for Caching

Comment: @Tim What can help me to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Ensure that you're not re-caching too frequently. The reason I think it might be a caching issue is because what you have in your graph is an almost constant and steady gradient of memory over time, which suggests to me that the memory usage is not due to end-user usage, because if that was the case, I would expect to see some irregularities, i.e. Spikes. Check your memcacher settings. I'm not sure what exactly to look for but I think you'll find something that 'isn't quite right' in there.

Comment: @Tim I've noticed that "Memory" is 30MB, but my LIMIT is 25MB. It's ok?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with MemCachier so forgive me if I'm wrong, but judging by the syntax, I think that's not the problem you're looking for. 30 MB Memory means you have 30 MB available to use, and that you have a limit of 25 MB for this app in particular, giving you 5 MB of 'padding' memory. 

On another note, just out of curiosity, have you checked your memory usage recently? Are you still getting high figures, or was that a one-off incident?

Comment: I've tried to restart the server and I get always the same thing

Comment: Okay so it's not your cache. But I still think you have a memory leak somewhere. Check your GC to ensure memory fragmentation is OK.

Comment: May you explain more about GC? Where I check it? Where can I read about it?

Comment: http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2015/02/19/optimizing-rails-for-memory-usage-part-2-tuning-the-gc/